# How to see full edit summary in revision box?

Tags: support, edit-summary

the edit summaries in the drop down use use to browse revisions of an answer looks truncated, like there's more to see.  How do I see the rest of the summary?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the full summary of your own edits listed in [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790359/sabgenton?tab=activity):

> [image]

When viewing specific question or answer that was edited, you can click the "edited [time] ago" link:

> [image]

And you will reach the revisions list, showing full summary of all edits made on that post. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6906310/revisions))

Comment: How did you click your way to the post revisions?

Comment: @sabgenton by clicking the "edited [time] ago" link.

Comment: Ah got it!  Top marks for finding my screen shot to :D

Comment: @sabgenton added screenshots with red circles, just for you. :-D

Comment: I just bet you to it but the bright red circles are pretty :D